# Ionic3 framework network.onConnect().subscribe not working?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created a little phone app with Ionic. I am trying to implement a bit logic where the component knows when its online or offline. To do so I am using the network plugin fom Ionic and it just does not work as expected.

instead of updating the

```
this.connected
```

value every time when I switch on / off the network, it will only do so if I switch it off / on AND do something like switching from landscape to portrait mode, or work on a different app for a while and come back to the app.

Really puzzled by that.

Here is the code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import {SurveyService} from "./survey.service";
import {Survey} from "../../Declarations/Survey";
import {SurveyPage} from "../survey/survey";
import {Network} from "@ionic-native/network";

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [SurveyService, Network]
})
export class HomePage {
    public surveys: Survey[] = [];
    public connected;
    public networkType;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
                private surveyService: SurveyService,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                platform: Platform,
                private network: Network) {


        this.checkForNetwork();
        this.surveyService.getAvailable().subscribe(surveys => {
            this.checkForNetwork();
            this.surveys = surveys;
        })
    }


    login() {

        this.googlePlus.login({
            'webClientId': '632130231957-dmjd154jhq1eenimedri3m0de6sh7tln.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    logout() {

        this.googlePlus.logout().then(() => {
            console.log("logged out");
        });

    }

    openSurvey = (survey: Survey) => {

        this.navCtrl.push(SurveyPage, {
            survey: survey
        });

    }

    checkForNetwork = () => {
        this.networkType= this.network.type;
        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            this.connected = false;
            this.network.type = null;
        });
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
            this.connected = 'network connected!';
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
                    this.connected = true;
                }
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked it out:

Turns out that ionic works perfectly fine, but I tried to change the view of my application depending on whether

```
this.connected
```

is true or false. I did not realize that I needed to tell Angular to refresh its view by using Application

applicationRef.tick();

in the right place. So basically, once the Ionic changes the value of this.connected you need to tell Angular about it, here is the corrected part of the code:

You need to inject ApplicationRef into the constructor

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                ...
                private appReference: ApplicationRef) {
                ...

checkForNetwork = () => {
    this.networkType= this.network.type;
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.connected = false;
        this.network.type = null;
        this.appReference.tick();
    });
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.connected = 'network connected!';
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
                this.connected = true;
                this.appReference.tick();
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```